# prometheus run using docker

Tags: docker, prometheus

This is the first time I am using docker to run a release file.

I installed docker using

```
npm install -g docker
```

I am trying to use Prometheus.
https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus

I followed following steps

1. Download Prometheus [https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/prometheus/]

   docker pull prom/prometheus

> C:\xampp\htdocs\prometheus>docker pull prom/prometheus
>
> Saved file tree to doc-filelist.js
>
> Copied JS to doc-script.js
>
> Compiled CSS to doc-style.css

2. Run docker [https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus]

   docker run --name prometheus -d -p 127.0.0.1:9090:9090 prom/prometheus

> C:\xampp\htdocs\prometheus>docker run --name prometheus -d -p 127.0.0.1:9090:9090 prom/prometheus
>
> Saved file tree to doc-filelist.js
>
> Copied JS to doc-script.js
>
> Compiled CSS to doc-style.css

I am not sure what is wrong. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are installing is this [docker](http://jbt.github.io/docker/src/docker.js.html) which is a documentation generator rather than this [docker](https://www.docker.com/why-docker) , which is a container technology.

So , refer to [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) to install the correct Docker first .Then execute the following commands:

```
# docker pull prom/prometheus
# docker run --name prometheus -d -p 127.0.0.1:9090:9090 prom/prometheus
```

Then open the browser and visit `http://127.0.0.1:9090` and you should see the Prometheus UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker to run Prometheus, make sure

1. Docker engine is installed.
2. Keep a configuration file (promethues.yml) file.
3. run the container using the command.

   docker run -d -p 9090:9090 -v /path_where_config_file_present/:/etc/prometheus -v /path_where_data_file_to_be_dumped/:/prometheus  prom/prometheus:v2.4.0 --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml